# How to set character encoding to a request in Restlet Framework?

Tags: rest, restlet

I am using the Restlet Framework to receive and send the data.

```
//Receiving the Request.
Request helpReq = new Request();
```

Here is my code where I want to send(set) the character encoding along with the response(helpRes)..

```
//Responding to the Request
Response helpRes = client.handle(helpReq);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding applies to representations sent along with request. See the Representation.characterSet property and the Request.entity one.